# Import provisionig profile in xcode version 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, provisioning-profile

I try to submit my app to the app store, but I have a problem that I can not fix. I can't archive the project beacuse this error: "no matching provisioning profiles found".
I create manually a provisioning profile in the member center, I download it and I double clicked to open in xcode.

The big problem is that in my build setting I can't select that. Xcode show me only a blank text area.

[screen 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ktxkacv2phlz8g6/Schermata%202015-09-22%20alle%2015.42.26.png?dl=0)

in the preferences the provisioning profiles is show !

[screen 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hiuah4srvn06be2/Schermata%202015-09-22%20alle%2015.46.16.png?dl=0)

Thank in advance for the helps !

Comment: Is there any way that you can set your provisioning profile to "Automatic"?  That helps me sometimes when I can't get mine to show up.

Comment: Do you have the correct private key installed on that machine?

Comment: watch this i hope it will help you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRlOdp4uZoo&index=1&list=PLIsEwuSHTg-1qc8_uu3-d7VRp3prmf2On

Comment: i can't set provisioning profile to automatic and i have the correct key installed on the machine. X code not show the option for signing, there is only "iphone developer" [screen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqo3w05pls8qsqo/Schermata%202015-09-22%20alle%2016.36.29.png?dl=0)

Comment: editor->show values fix my problems, thank you all anyway !

Comment: To submit to the store, you need an iPhone Distribution signing identity and provisioning profile.